# `use strict` не переводит функцию в строгий режим?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Если написать `use strict` в косых апострофах, то функция не переходит в строгий режим. Верно ли это поведение?

```js
function f() { // Нет строгого режима - всё хорошо
  return 010;
}

console.log(f());
```

```js
function f() { // Почему тут нет строгого режима?
  `use strict`;
  return 010;
}

console.log(f());
```

```js
function f() { // Строгий режим, поэтому ошибка
  'use strict';
  return 010;
}

console.log(f());
```

```js
function f() { // Строгий режим, поэтому ошибка
  "use strict";
  return 010;
}

console.log(f());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В соответствии с текущим стандартом это верно.

Из стандарта
[Директивы и "use strict"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-directive-prologues-and-the-use-strict-directive)

A *Use Strict Directive* is an *ExpressionStatement* in a *Directive Prologue* whose **StringLiteral** is either the exact code unit sequences "use strict" or 'use strict'. A *Use Strict Directive* may not contain an EscapeSequence or LineContinuation.

**StringLiteral** определена как

```
StringLiteral::
   " DoubleStringCharactersopt "
   ' SingleStringCharactersopt '
```

То что в косых апострофах называется [Template Literal Lexical Components](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-template-literal-lexical-components). К **StringLiteral** это не относится.

Answer (score 7):

А так в [документации](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_14.1) написано:

> A Use Strict Directive is an ExpressionStatement in a Directive Prologue whose StringLiteral is either the **exact** character sequences **"use strict"** or **'use strict'**. A Use Strict Directive may not contain an EscapeSequence or LineContinuation.

P.S. Вопрос на инглише https://stackoverflow.com/q/5214391/5441700

Comment: Ссылка на ES5 - тогда не было шаблонных строк, так что принимаю соседний ответ как более точный и полный.